# Shell script to backup all databases and www directory

Tags: mysql, shell, backup

I have a simple shell script which backup once a week whole `www` directory and single database. It is working perfectly.. Now I want to extend it a little bit and make it to backup all databases not just one. How can I do this?

This is the current script

```
#!/bin/bash
NOW=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H%M")
FILE="backup.$NOW.tar"
BACKUP_DIR="/home/user/backups/"
WWW_DIR="/var/www/"

DB_USER="dbuser"
DB_PASS="dbpass"
DB_NAME="dbName"
DB_FILE="backup.$NOW.sql"

WWW_TRANSFORM='s,^home/user/www,'
DB_TRANSFORM='s,^home/user/backups,database,'


tar -cf $BACKUP_DIR/$FILE --transform $WWW_TRANSFORM $WWW_DIR
mysqldump -u$DB_USER -p$DB_PASS $DB_NAME > $BACKUP_DIR/$DB_FILE

tar --append --file=$BACKUP_DIR/$FILE --transform $DB_TRANSFORM  $BACKUP_DIR/$DB_FILE
rm $BACKUP_DIR/$DB_FILE
gzip -9 $BACKUP_DIR/$FILE

echo 'backup finished', $FILE
```

Comment: `man mysqldump`   `/all-databases`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple use `show databases` command. Read all the databases in for loop like this and call `mysqldump` command

```
databases=`mysql --user=$DB_USER --password=$DB_PASS -e "SHOW DATABASES;" | tr -d "| " | grep -v Database`

for db in $databases; do
        echo "Dumping database: $db"
        mysqldump --force --opt --user=$DB_USER--password=$DB_PASS --databases $db > $BACKUP_DIR/`date +%Y%m%d`.$db.sql
done
```

Comment: Thank's for the answer. In this case I just paste this in my script and remove `DB_NAME="dbName"` .. let me try.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is on shared hosting.. when I run the script now I've got `Dumping database: information_schema
mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'user_table--password=mypassword'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying to connect`

Comment: you will get whatever name is given in mysql. Rest you can append,prepend anything with db_name in your script.

Comment: I've put correct username/password and I've got this `mysqldump: Got error: 1044: Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema' when using LOCK TABLES` then I tried to put after mysqldump `--single-transaction` but then I got this `mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `CLIENT_STATISTICS`': Access denied; you need (at least one of) the PROCESS,SUPER privilege(s) for this operation (1227)`

Comment: You can grant privilege  to the lock tables on your user.

Comment: I can't.. I don't have this permissions on this shared host. However I have made one condition to ignore information_schema table and now will test it. I think is failed because I can't/don't have permission to dump this database.

Comment: better, you can skip those unwanted database for mysqldump.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

USER="root"
PASSWORD="PASSWord"
OUTPUT="/root"


rm "$OUTPUT/*gz" > /dev/null 2>&1

databases=`mysql --user=$USER --password=$PASSWORD -e "SHOW DATABASES;" | tr -d "| " | grep -v Database`

for db in $databases; do
    if [[ "$db" != "information_schema" ]] && [[ "$db" != _* ]] ; then
        now="$(date +'%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S')"
        echo "Dumping database: $db"
        mysqldump --user=$USER --password=$PASSWORD --default-character-set=utf8 $db | gzip > $OUTPUT/$db.`date +%Y%m%d`.gz
    fi
done
```